# GitHub Plugin error causing Git servers not loading after Jenkins upgrade

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Experiencing the following error with [GitHub plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github/) when starting up Jenkins:

> WARNING hudson.model.Descriptor#load: Failed to load /var/lib/jenkins/github-plugin-configuration.xml
>
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: github-plugin-configuration
> at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:81)
>
> Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /var/lib/jenkins/github-plugin-configuration.xml
> at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:199)

Jenkins version: `2.387.1` 
GitHub plugin version: `1.37.0`

*github-plugin-configuration.xml*

```xml
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<github-plugin-configuration plugin="github@1.37.0">
  <configs/>
</github-plugin-configuration>
```

I also can't see any of the **jobs** on Jenkins, despite being placed on the `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs` directory.

**What I've tried**

- Restarting Jenkins.
- Checked that the `$JENKINS_HOME` var is set correctly. All the plugins are being loaded except for the GitHub one. Jobs are not being loaded, but idk if this plugin is what it's causing the issue.
- Checked that all dependencies for the GitHub Plugin are installed.
- Found a [fix](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-masters/github-plugin-settings-not-loaded-on-startup) for this problem online, but I don't have the *Support Core* plugin installed, so I don't think that's it.

Comment: did you try this solution?
https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-masters/github-plugin-settings-not-loaded-on-startup

Comment: I referenced that same link on the "What I've tried" section: I don't have the Support Core plugin installed, so I don't think that's it.

Comment: I also tried installing the Support Core plugin, and it did not solve this.

Comment: This is https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-71786

Comment: I ended up recreating Jenkins from scratch. Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 1):

if you installed shining panda plugging for python, remove it and try
[reference](https://community.jenkins.io/t/github-plugin-configuration-does-not-load-after-service-restart/8956)